# Problem printing text that has just been written

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a simple HTML webpage with some JavaScript. I take information from a JSON file, and with help of JavaScript, I format the text and prepare it to export to a CSV file.

The problem comes when I write the text on the page, and after I try to read it. It gives me an **Empty** string, so I can't export it.

For testing, I'm just writing the output with `console.log`, but I'm not getting the response that I expect.

**JavaScript**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    convertData();
});

function convertData() {
    fetch('info.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => showData(data))
    .then(print())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}

function showData(data) {
    const container = document.getElementById("container");

    for (var i = 0; i < data["data"].length; i++) {
        var obj = data["data"][i];

        container.innerHTML += "<br>" + obj["field1"] + "; " + obj["field2"] + "; "
    }
}

function print() {
    const container = document.getElementById("container");
    const data = container.innerHTML;
    console.log(data);   
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I use `container.innerHTML += "....."`, it shows me the content correctly, but when I print it, it doesn't show properly.

I can't use `TimeOuts`, because I don't know how long it can take. It can be 3 seconds on the first time and 40 seconds con the second one.

Comment: How can i then solve it? I tried adding `async function showData(data) {...}` but nothing changed

Comment: The prolem is with `.then(print())` change it to `.then(print)` I'm also working on a more detailed answer

Comment: `.then(print())` — You are *calling* `print` **immediately** and passing its return value to `then()` instead of passing a function to `then()`. See the duplicate which is about the same problem, only with `setTimeout` instead of `then`.

Comment: Re edit — *I can't use `TimeOuts`, because I don't know how long it can take. It can be 3 seconds on the first time and 40 seconds con the second one.* — Nobody is suggesting you should use `setTimeout`. The duplicate question explains why you have the problem you do. As my previous comment highlights, `then` (which you are using) and `setTimeout` (which the duplicate uses and makes the same mistake with) work in similar ways.

Comment: @Quentin I don't think that's the right duplicate link, the problem seems to be about `.then(print())` vs `.then(() => print())`, so I think we should change the link to something like [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286233/pass-a-javascript-function-as-parameter)

Comment: @nickzoum — Removing the need for arguments to be passed to the callback makes simpler solutions possible, but solutions in the (slightly) more complex case still work for the simple case.

Comment: @Quentin I think there is some miscommunication,  I mean the problem is that `.then(print())` is the same as `.then(undefined)`, the solution to the problem is to use either `.then(print)` or `.then(() => print())`

Comment: @nickzoum — Or `.then(function () { print(); })` which is [what the duplicate recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8196237/19068).

Comment: @Quentin fair enough, I just mean I thnk it's easier to understand the problem with the other question

Comment: Honestly, reading the awnser of the dupplicate question you gave me, i won't be capable of solving the question. The awnser that is below solved my problem and I understood why its happening. Thanks @nickzoum for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you're immediately invoking `print`. What you're essentially doing is calling `print` right away (before the fetch request is even sent) and passing the return value of print (`undefined`) to the `then` call. What you want to do is pass a function as a paramter so that function is called when the previous promises are resolved.

Just change

```js
function convertData() {
    fetch('info.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => showData(data))
    .then(print())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

To

```js
function convertData() {
    fetch('info.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => showData(data))
    .then(print)
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

Or

```js
function convertData() {
    fetch('info.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => showData(data))
    .then(() => print())
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

It's also a bit unsafe to use a plain load listener without checking if the  respective load event has already triggered, what I like to do is:

```js
if (document.readyState === "complete") convertData();
else addEventListener("load", convertData);
```

Here is a functional example with a mock fetch:

```js
function mockFetch() {
  const data = {
    data: [{
        field1: "foo",
        field2: "bar"
      },
      {
        field1: "foobar",
        field2: "_"
      }
    ]
  };
  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const response = new Response(jsonData);
  return Promise.resolve(response);
}

if (document.readyState === "complete") convertData();
else addEventListener("load", convertData);

function convertData() {
  mockFetch()
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(showData)
    .then(print)
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

function showData(data) {
  const container = document.getElementById("container");

  for (var i = 0; i < data["data"].length; i++) {
    var obj = data["data"][i];

    container.innerHTML += "<br>" + obj["field1"] + "; " + obj["field2"] + "; "
  }
}

function print() {
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  const data = container.innerHTML;
  console.log(data);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Some other notes:
It's safer to use to `let` or `const` instead of `var` inside `for` loops [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58483101/for-of-loop-should-i-use-const-or-let).

You can replace `obj["field1"]` with `obj.field1`, you can accesss it normally, you should reserve the `["param"]` notation for when the key is not a valid property name (i.e. contains spaces, starts with numbers, contains invalid characters...)

Comment: Thanyou, that solved my problem, but I don't really understand why it works when i call it without the parenthesis `()`

Comment: @Maida when you call `.then` or `.addEventlistener` or any similar function you want to pass a function as a parameter so the `then` function can call the function when it's ready. In this part `.then(response => response.json())` you are also passing a function

Comment: Oh Okay @nick zoum, i understand. Unanfortunatly for the site, someone closed my question, and this may be usefull for some other people. Thanks,

Comment: @Maida people can still view the question and the answer, it just means no further answers can be posted. I've also added some extra notes to the answers, that I hope are helpful.